# TreeView doesn't perform UI virtualization

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, virtualization

I've been checking out the UI virtualization feature for WPF's TreeView control, which as I understand, is available since .NET 3.5 SP1.

I made a simple project to make sure that UI virtualization is performed correctly, and found out that it doesn't work at all - all of the items are retrieved rather than just the ones currently displayed on the screen.

My XAML looks like this

```
<TreeView x:Name="myTree" Height="150" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
          ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True" />
```

And my code behind

```
    public IEnumerable Items { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        Items = GenerateList();
        this.DataContext = this;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private IEnumerable GenerateList()
    {
        MyList list = new MyList();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            list.Add("Item " + i);
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Note that `MyList` is my own implementation of `IList` that holds an `ArrayList` and does nothing more than forward calls to the held `ArrayList` and write to the console which method/property was called. For example:

```
public object this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("get[{0}]", index));
        return _list[index];
    }
    set
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("set[{0}]", index));
        _list[index] = value;
    }
}
```

If I replace my TreeView with a ListBox, UI virtualization works as expected - i.e. only ~20 items are requested and not the whole 1000.

Am I doing something wrong here?

**EDIT**

I've also tried replacing the default `ItemsPanel` to `VirtualizingStackPanel`, as suggested , but I'm getting the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default `ItemsPanelTemplate` for TreeView is `StackPanel` and not `VirtualizingStackPanel` that's why you can't see virtualization in it. Whereas for ListBox default ItemsPanelTemplate is VirtualizingStackPanel that's why setting `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"` works for ListBox.

To enable virtualization on your TreeView apart from setting property `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"`,  you need to override the its default itemsPanelTemplate like this -

```
<TreeView x:Name="myTree" Height="150" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.CleanUpVirtualizedItem="myTree_CleanUpVirtualizedItem"
          ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True">
    <TreeView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True" />                   
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemsPanel>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: I've already tried exactly that (the only difference being that I didn't set `IsItemsHost="True"`, which I believe doesn't make a difference in this case - correct me if I'm wrong). Sorry I didn't mention it.

Comment: How you reached to the point that all 1000 items are fetched and virtualization is not coming into play. I tried hooking an event 'VirtualizingStackPanel.CleanUpVirtualizedItem' to the treeView and it gets called as soon as any item >20 comes in view. Check yourself by hooking that event and you will see that vistualization is working. Updated the answer. :)

Comment: You don't need to override the `ItemsPanelTemplate`, setting `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing` is enough.

Comment: @RV1987 I will only be able to check this tomorrow, but either way, I see that 1000 items are retrieved because I'm logging all access to the list's elements. When I use `ListBox`, only 20 items are accessed; when I use `TreeView`, all 1000 items are accessed. You can't argue with that no matter what you get by hooking that event.

Comment: @H.B. - Yeah, i just tested it and simply setting this property enables virtualization for TreeView and it seems to working fine at my end.:)

Comment: @Lester - Can you show code where you are logging it since indexer property is not getting hit at the time of UI rendering. UI will internally calls the enumerator to fetch the items.

Comment: @RV1987 The logging code is the one provided in my question. The indexer property does get hit for me; I'm not sure why for you it doesn't. I'm trying to implement something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization) for hierarchical controls and wanted to make sure the behavior for fetching items from the `ItemsSource` is the same for `ListBox` and `TreeView`. For some strange reason it looks like it's not. However, I think I understand now this behavior doesn't have anything to do with UI virtualization, but with `ItemsControls`.

Comment: For clarification, the behavior I'm talking about is the one mentioned in the article: "When an ItemsControl is bound to an IList implementation, rather than an IEnumerable implementation, it will not enumerate the entire list, and instead only accesses the items required for display." I might open a new, more refined question for this.